# How do I send an email through "mail" in Linux for a username containing an ampersand?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

For a username "**`A&B`**"

```
[abuser@myserver] chfn -f "A&B"
Changing finger information for abuser
Password:
Finger information changed.
[abuser@myserver] mail -s Test myemail@mycompany.com
Hello World!
Cc:
[abuser@myserver]
```

When this mail arrives, "**`&`**" appears to be replaced by the username in the From field in the email.

```
From: AAbuserB [abuser@myserver]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the Mail Transport Agent (MTA) handling of `&` characters in the mailbox name in `/etc/passwd`

From the [passwd man page](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=4&topic=passwd):

> gcos-field  is the  user's  real  name,  along  with
>                            information  to  pass  along  in a mail-
>                            message  heading.  (It  is  called   the
>                            gcos-field  for  historical reasons.) An
>                            ``&'' (ampersand) in this  field  stands
>                            for  the  login name (in cases where the
>                            login name  appears  in  a  user's  real
>                            name).

The workaround in this case is to explicitly set the From address in the mail client.

For example, using `mutt` (as suggested by @mailq):

```
~/.muttrc

set realname="A&B"
set from="ab@myserver"
set use_from=yes
```

Sending a test email...

```
echo "Test body" | mutt -s "Test" myemail@mycompany.com
```

Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
mail -a "From: A&B <abuser@myserver>" -s Test myemail@mycompany.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get "mail: invalid option -- a".  Furthermore, this is for an automated system email that doesn't hard-code the from address.

Comment: You seem to have a very old mail command or different implementation of it than I, then. Have you tried to escape & character: `chfn -f "A\&B"`?

Comment: Yep - escaping doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Quoted Printable Encoding:

```
chfn -f "=?ISO-8859-15?Q?A=26B?="
```

where `=26` is the ampersand. Looks ugly, but should do the trick.

**Edit:** It is not `mail`, but you should then try other alternatives: Use sendmail (the interface of your MTA and not sendmail itself). Or `mutt` is also good for scripted sending of mails. The `mail` command is too restricted in functionality in this case. And if you really need a `mail` command then you need to write a wrapper called `mail` that internally calls `mutt` for sending.

Comment: Apologies for slow reply. Doesn't seem to work... chfn -f "=?ISO-8859-15?Q?A=26B?="... chfn: full name: '=' is not allowed.

Comment: @NickPierpoint Then write a bug report for `mail` or use other alternatives as described in my edit.

Comment: I get the same behaviour using `mutt` - I presume the issue is with the mta (`sendmail` in this case).